# The difference between Istio's `DestinationRule` vs Kubernetes `Service`?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I just read the documentation of istio 1.0.0, especially its concept. There is one thing that I am trying to understand, especially the existence of [`DestinationRule`](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#rule-configuration). So, before using Istio, the only way to expose pods is through Kubernetes's `Service` object. Now, using Istio, there are `DestinationRule` and `VirtualService`.

I understand that in Kubernetes's service, we can define what pod's label should the `service` routes the traffic. In istio, we also capable of do that by using `DestionationRule`'s `spec.subsets.label` field. What happen if we have `Service` and `DestinationRule` object in the same namespace? Does it conflicted each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They complement each other. You still have to define a Kubernetes service, but the Istio `DestinationRules` will allow you to refine "subsets" in that service, via labels, and then route traffic intelligently between subsets used in a `VirtualService` object. You can still see the Kubernetes Service as the global entry point, but Istio will take the routing a step further by letting you declaring "versions" that may point to different deployments.

See in the istio docs ( https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/ ) how the `VirtualService` definition relates to the subsets declared in `DestinationRules`.

The labels that you can see in subsets have to match labels set on your deployments/pods.

Comment: The correct link is https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/