# What is the difference between Istio VirtualService and Kubernetes Service?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

As I understand, Istio `VirtualService` is kind of abstract thing, which tries to add an interface to the actual implementation like the service in Kubernetes or something similar in Consul.

When use Kubernetes as the underlying platform for Istio, is there any difference between Istio `VirtualService` and Kubernetes `Service` or are they the same?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719932/the-difference-between-istios-destinationrule-vs-kubernetes-service/51723113#51723113

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Istio's VirtualServices provides, as every Istio's extensions, some additionals features such as external traffic routing/management (Pod to external communication, HTTPS external communication, routing, url rewriting...).

Take a look at this doc about it for more details : https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service

They can be both useful, as you need "classic" Services to manage ingress traffic or service-to-service communication.

Comment: so when using kubernetes, does the virtual service use k8s service to route traffic? How the two cooperate?

Answer (score 18):

#### Kubernetes service

Kubernetes `service` manage a pod's networking. It specifies whether your pods are exposed internally (`ClusterIP`), externally (`NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`) or as a CNAME of other DNS entries (`externalName`).

As an example this `foo-service` will expose the pods with label `app: foo`.  Any requests sent to the node on port `30007` will be forwarded to the pod on port `80`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: foo
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30007
```

#### Istio virtualservice

Istio `virtualservice` is one level higher than Kuberenetes `service`. It can be used to apply traffic routing, fault injection, retries and many other configurations to `services`.

As an example this `foo-retry-virtualservice` will retry 3 times with a timeout 2s each for failed requests to `foo`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: foo-retry-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - foo
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: foo
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
```

Another example of this `foo-delay-virtualservice` will apply a 0.5s delay to 0.1% of requests to `foo`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: foo-delay-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - foo
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        percentage:
          value: 0.1
        fixedDelay: 5s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: foo
```

#### Ref

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/
https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services

Comment: Shouldn't the VirtualService' `spec.http.route.destination.host` be `foo-service` instead of `foo`? https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Destination says: 
"The destination.host should unambiguously refer to a service in the service registry."

Answer (score 6):

**Virtual Service:**

It defines a set of traffic routing rules to apply to a kubernetes service or subset of service based on the matching criteria. This is something similar to kubernetes Ingress object. It plays a key role on Istio's traffic management flexible and powerful.

**Kubernetes Service:**

It can be a logical set of pods and defined as an abstraction on top of pods which provides single DNS name or IP.