# Why explicit protocol setting cause traffic routing error?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I write a virtual service to test header based routing

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: http-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - http-app.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
    - match:
        - headers:
            canary-token:
              exact: haha
      route:
        - destination:
            host: http-app.default.svc.cluster.local
            subset: canary
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: http-app.default.svc.cluster.local
            subset: stable
```

The traffic routing is right when service is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-app
  namespace: default
  labels:
    env: prod
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: http-app
  ports:
    - port: 3011
      targetPort: 3011
```

```bash
[2023-08-28T04:00:01.156Z] "GET /mesh HTTP/1.1" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 0 78 645 644 "192.168.65.4, 127.0.0.6" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54" "24cb1d39-33f6-4e07-8ba5-fefc4c656498" "nginx-app.local" "10.1.13.85:3011" outbound|3011|canary|http-app.default.svc.cluster.local 10.1.13.93:44452 10.104.186.154:3011 127.0.0.6:0 - -
```

But when I explicit set protocol to http like this

```
  ports:
    - port: 3011
      targetPort: 3011
      appProtocol: http
```

or this

```
  ports:
    - name: http-app
      port: 3011
      targetPort: 3011
```

The traffic routing will be allow_any

```
[2023-08-28T11:23:10.344Z] "GET /mesh HTTP/1.1" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 0 78 652 652 "192.168.113.118,192.168.65.4, 127.0.0.6" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54" "f54af48b-6f67-4f64-ba05-2d5d9215fd8c" "nginx-app.local" "10.104.186.154:3011" PassthroughCluster 10.1.13.93:38016 10.104.186.154:3011 127.0.0.6:0 - allow_any
```

Why after explicit set protocol, the header based routing not work?

Comment: Istio supports both automatic and explicit protocol selection.  The access log shared, in that the response returned are with http 200 status code in both the cases and there is no error.  More details of protocol selection are in https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/#explicit-protocol-selection

Comment: As per the official document,ALLOW\_ANY is enabled by default under meshconfig while installing Istio and also Http status code 200 is not an error.

[https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/)

Comment: Can you check if a [`istioctl analyze`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl-analyze/) would yield any clue? And check Envoy's configuration dump (`istioctl proxy-config routes <pod-name>`) to understand how the routes are being set up internally.

Comment: Do you have any other VirtualServices or ServiceEntries or anything else set on that same host name? I tried to replicate this, however, it worked fine for me (no traffic sent to the PassthroughCluster)

Comment: you must verify that the Istio sidecar proxy is injected properly in the deployment pods, you can use the `kubectl get pods` command to check the status of the pods and ensure that the sidecar proxy is running!

Answer (score 0):

```
  ports:
    - port: 3011
      appProtocol: http
or 
    - name: http-app
```

Note: When you configure name or appProtocol, Istio will treat the traffic on that port as plain HTTP. This means Istio will not inspect or manipulate HTTP headers, including the canary-token header, for routing purposes. It means that the header-based routing rules defined in your VirtualService won't be applied, and traffic will be allowed to flow freely to the specified port without considering the canary-token header.

Solution:

```
  ports:
    - port: 3011
      targetPort: 3011
```

If you want Istio to perform header-based routing based on the canary-token header, you should not explicitly set the protocol to http or name the port as http-app. By default, Istio performs L7 routing, inspecting HTTP headers and other application-layer attributes to make routing decisions.

So, to enable header-based routing, you should use the original configuration for your service's ports without specifying the appProtocol or using the name http-app. This way, Istio will continue to inspect the HTTP headers and apply the routing rules you defined in your VirtualService.

Reference:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/

[What is the difference between Istio VirtualService and Kubernetes Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743219/what-is-the-difference-between-istio-virtualservice-and-kubernetes-service)

Comment: `This means Istio will not inspect or manipulate HTTP headers`
This sounds reasonable, but where can I learn about it?

Comment: spec:
  hosts:
    - http-app.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:  (You handle HTTP traffic explicitly based on the command in your VirtualService.) If you need to specify the protocol explicitly, consider using Istio's protocol-specific routing features. Istio supports routing based on HTTP, HTTPS, gRPC, and other protocols. You can define separate VirtualService rules for each protocol if needed. But not change the Service yaml file as above.